# Include a text version of my message during mail() in PHP

Tags: php, email

SpamAssassin thinks I can improve:

```
MIME_HTML_ONLY  Message only has text/html MIME parts
You should also include a text version of your message (text/plain)
```

How can i do this if my script is actually the following:

```
$to = 'My user name <user@domain.com>';

$message = 'my html message here';

$headers .= 'From: me <noreply@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($to, 'My subject', $message, $headers);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make it `multipart/alternative` and then put both versions in `$message`

Comment: `mail()` is very limited, stop using it.